# WebSockets draft hixie 76 protocol for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, websocket

I'm building a client on iPhone to connect to one server using WebSockets draft hixie 76 protocol.

I already tried [UnittWebSocketClient](http://code.google.com/p/unitt/wiki/UnittWebSocketClient), but they don't have support for that protocol.

Does anyone know any library that supports that protocol on iPhone? It could be Objective-C, C or C++.

Answer (score 1):

The version in SVN of the UnittWebSocketClient should work with hixie76 servers. Use the WebSocket00.h header. Let me know if you have difficulties. You can refer to the UnittWebSocketClient00Tests for sample code. Make sure you look in the SVN trunk and not the libraries available for download on the website.